# android secure connection with server not working

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I am working on an application in which i have to make secure conenction with server.
The server had jks keystore and server side developed using java which i imported in my application as bks.

Here is command i sued to import certificate from jks to bks

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  trust.jks -destkeystore newcertificate.bks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS  -srcstorepass "password" -deststorepass "mycert" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-144.jar

and follow all the steps in following 
[Secure connection with httpclient in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943915/secure-connection-with-httpclient-in-android)

but its not working. I am getting ioexception message as "No peer cerrifate".

Can anybody tried such thing. Any code snippet will be of great use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned here. and solved..

[steps to generate self signed keys for server and client](http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/)

The link explains all the things. It works great...